# Unable to ask question in stackoverflow by not able to validate tags

Tags: bug

[image: Unable to validate the tags after typing the space key]

Hi everyone.I have something wrong with the question site.When I am trying to validate a tag(by click the space key on keyboard),it fail.Please,anyone?
**Edit**: The link has the same problem.After referring to others question,it seems there are a couple of problems for asking question.For example:Unable to edit post,unable to show tag list,toolbar disappear, etc.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks!